# Seating arrangement problem at circular table with three categories

Tags: combinatorics

I am interested in the number of possible seating arrangements at a round table with $N$ seats (only considering the order and not the orientation in the room). Each seat will have a red, blue, or yellow card. If there are at least $k$ red cards, how many combinations of seating arrangements are possible?

I started by thinking that there are $N \choose k$ ways to fix the minimal number of red cards. Each arrangement, I can rotate $N$ times. That leaves me with ${N \choose k} \cdot \frac{1}{N}$ options. For a given arrangement, I have $N-k$ seats left. For those, I can choose from 3 categories, giving me $3^{N-k}$ options for each of the ${N \choose k} \cdot \frac{1}{6}$ arrangements. Now I don't know how to continue because I think I need to further exclude some cases due to rotation symmetry, but I don't know how many. Particularly since adding the additional red cards will lead to some arrangements that were already considered in my first step.

Comment: Please edit your question to show what you have attempted and explain where you are stuck.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig Thanks for the suggestion, I did

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With unknown variable numbers of different colours, I don't think necklace type symmetries is supposed to be considered.

So using the general formula  ${(N-1)}!$ for circular arrangements, the answer would be

$$\sum_{\substack{r+b+y\\r\ge k\; \land\; b,y \ge 0}}^N \frac{(N-1)!}{r!b!y!}$$

Comment: The table with seats can be rotated, and arrangements that can be aligned with rotation are the same arrangement for this problem. Is your formula right for this case? Is the problem considering the symmetry too difficult, or what is the matter?

Comment: Yes, rotation of table has been taken into account, but color symmetries can arise of the necklace type, but unless specific numbers are given, how will we know. See necklace combinatorics,  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Necklace_(combinatorics)

Comment: Are you talking about the chirality mentioned in the wiki? For my application, two arrangements that would be chiral to each other would be considered distinct.